# UWP virtual keyboard pushes content up

Tags: keyboard, uwp, virtual

I have an UWP app where my robots face gets pushed up when the virtual keyboard opens. Is it possible to have the scrollviewer stay in place and have the textbox stay in view when the virtual keyboard opens.

I see you can subscribe to the opening and hiding events but that does not give me any options on which ui elements can stay or hide. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/respond-to-the-presence-of-the-touch-keyboard

```
<Page
    x:Class="VirtualKeyboardFix.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VirtualKeyboardFix"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer >
            <Image Source="image.png" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image: Image of robot with hidden face]

Comment: Normally the content gets pushed up if there's not enough space for the keyboard to show. Is this the case here?

Comment: Does adding an image help answer that question? Oh. I got what you mean.  The image is about the same size as the screen in this instance.

Comment: You can try manually setting the offset (negative) of the textbox when it gets focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes that is the answer Justin XL. Thanks a lot. If you want to post it as a reply instead of a comment then I will mark it as the  answer.

Just in case anyone has the same problem.

```
namespace VirtualKeyboardFix
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += MainPage_Showing;
            InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += MainPage_Hiding;
        }

        private void MainPage_Showing(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
        {
            args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = false;
            InputTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, args.OccludedRect.Height + 10);
        }

        private void MainPage_Hiding(InputPane sender, InputPaneVisibilityEventArgs args)
        {
            args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = false;
            InputTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Fixed Image]

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. Well deserved. ;)